# Toggle buttons contents when single button clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, keyboard

I am working on windows phone keyboard project for Urdu language. I have created custom keyboard layout in XAML and added characters for non-shift keys and working well.

But now I am stuck in shift key functionality. For example when user click shift key then characters should be toggled of other keys; just like in English keyboard. After searching I got only single toggle button solution that is not enough for me because my situation is different.

I need help to continue with project. If you have different efficient approach please suggest me with little example. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: more context please? what is `single toggle button solution` and why is it not suitable for your situation?

Comment: @kennyzx Single toggle button like ON/OFF button. But I need when someone click on Shift button then the characters of other button change like when we click shift button in keyboard then keys character must change. Like in english keyboard keys change to Capitals letters.

Comment: OK, I need to make clear your requirement a little further: after user presses this `shift key`, all characters should be toggled to other keys, like `Caps Lock` shifts all chars into uppercase, until user presses this `shift key` again (shifts to lowercase in the `Caps Lock` analogy), right?

Comment: Yeah that is true, the character on button should be changed visually as well. In my case Urdu language contain 36 characters. I have implemented 26 characters for non-shift and other 10 similar and less useful characters in shift-key press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The simple way**

The simple way is making 2 keyboards with identical layout, one for displaying the normal characters and the other is for displaying the "shifted characters". Stack one keyboard on top of the other, and toggle the visibility of the keyboards based on the state of the `shift button`, you can do this in the `shift button`'s `Checked` and `Unchecked` event handlers (declare shift button as a `ToggleButton`).

**The binding way**

If you are using [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mvvm/info) pattern, you can bind the shift key state to a `Boolean property` in you view model, for example, `ShiftPress`, so when you toggle the shift key, the `ShiftPress` is updated automatically.

And this time you only need to define one keyboard. And you need to bind the key's UI and Command (the execution logic when a key is pressed) to this `ShiftPress` property.

And you end up with a keyboard something like this (*this is not working code, just illustrating how to bind key's UI and command to view model properties*).

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="myKeyboard" ItemsSource="{Binding Characters}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Char, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}, 
                ConverterParameter={Binding ShiftPress, RelativeResource...}}", 
                Command="{Binding KeyPressCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Char}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```